# Bridging networks without NAT: how it's done?

Tags: routing, nat, layer2, layer3, bridge

I have quite limited networking experience, so probably i'm asking about very simple things. I'm reading about linux bridge interfaces, and documentation states that there is no NAT by default and bridge interface just passes over packets as-is from one network to another. That confuses me: i'm imagining a LAN-behind-WiFi setup where my machine (let's name it `access-point`) can be connected to WiFi access point and share internet connection by bridging `wireless0` to `eth0`. The LAN itself would have some own address range (say, 192.168.0.0/24) and, if i understand it correctly, connection would be processed in following way:

- lan-device-1: send this frame with MAC 00::01 and with encapsulated dns query and source address 192.168.0.1 / target address 8.8.8.8
    to eth0
- access-point: just pushes frame from eth0 to wireless0
- 8.8.8.8: extracts DNS query, prepares answer, but sees source address 192.168.0.1
- some wild magic appears and forces response to go out to access-point IP address rather than to lan-device-1 address
- access-point: receives answer from 8.8.8.8, wild magic reappears and tells access-point that this response belongs to lan-device-1 rather than access-point, so response is flushed down to eth0 with correct MAC address

Of course we live in world with no magic, so those assumptions are wrong. But how then packets are routed to correct destinations? It would be simple if NAT would be in place, but it isn't and i can't understand how A) remote machine knows where to send response and B) how intermediatry (access-point in example) differentiates it's own traffic from bridged traffic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be confusing layer-2 and layer-3. Bridging is not routing. Bridging has nothing to do with layer-3 addresses, and routing removes the layer-2 addresses. Routers route packets, and bridges switch frames.

Routing happens at layer-3 with layer-3, e.g. IP, addresses. Routing routes layer-3 packets between networks.

Bridging happens with layer-2, e.g. MAC, addresses. Bridging delivers layer-2 frames directly from host-to-host on the same network.

If a packet is destined for a different network, the host will address the layer-3 packet to the destination host and the layer-2 frame used to encapsulate the layer-3 packet to the layer-2 address of its configured gateway (normally a router). A router will strip off the layer-2 frame, losing the layer-2 frame and addresses, inspect the destination layer-3 address on the packet, and forward the packet to the next interface, building a new frame for the next network.

Bridges that have all interfaces using the same layer-2 protocol, e.g. ethernet switches, are called transparent bridges, and they simply inspect the frame for the layer-2 address, switching it to an interface found in its MAC address table, or flooding it to all other interfaces if the destination MAC address is not in its MAC address table.

If a bridge connects two different layer-2 protocols, e.g. a WAP connecting ethernet and Wi-Fi, it must translate the frames between the different layer-2 protocols, and they are called translating bridges. They still use a MAC address table to determine the interface to which they will switch frames. Both ethernet and Wi-Fi use compatible 48-bit MAC addresses, so the addressing can remain the same, although the frames are different.

---

> Bridging networks without NAT: how it's done?

NAT really has nothing to do with routing or bridging. NAT is simply translating either the source, destination, or both layer-3 addresses in layer-3 packets, which are never seen by a layer-2 bridge.

Remember, bridging is on the same network, routing is between networks, and NAT is translating addresses to other addresses.

---

You cannot use RFC 1918 (or some other) addresses on the public internet, e.g. to `8.8.8.8`. Non-global addresses must be translated to public addresses before they are sent on the public Internet. Not all networks use private addressing, but any that do must use some form of NAT to translate private addresses to public addresses before sending packets to the public Internet.

Your WAP (access point) is simply a bridge, and the NAT happens somewhere else before the packets from your `192.168.0.0/24` network are sent to the public Internet.

Comment: Now i'm confused even more since i was sure that bridge ties *different* networks together (probably docker bridge is just somewhat other than i thought), so i was trying to understand how anything with address in network A will end on device with address in network B. Is the assumption that in example above wi-fi termination point should see bridged device just as any other device in it's network correct?

Comment: Essentially, a bridge connects initially distinct networks into a single, larger network (=L2 segment or broadcast domain).

Comment: @Etki, a WAP (Wireless Access Point) is a translating bridge, but it simply bridges (and translates) layer-2 frames on a single layer-3 network. Routers route packets between layer-3 networks. (What happens in an host/server/VM is off-topic here.) If you search here, you will find many explanations of the network layers, abstraction, and encapsulation. For example, the edit to [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/32213/8499) explains what happens from an application on a host to an application on another host, both on the same and another network.

Comment: Oh, so i guess some of my misconceptions are gone now. I was sure that linux bridge interface operates on L3 and does some magic to bind L3 networks together (again, got that idea from so-called docker bridge); now i understand (correct me if i'm wrong) that it operates on L2 and just forwards/filters/unknown unicasts L2 frames to other interface(s), allowing to use linux device as a regular switch.

Comment: I really can't answer what happens inside a host (that is off-topic here). Different host OSes can do it differently, and they may have different terminology (Linux frequently ignores the RFCs). I answered from the perspective of a network, which is what is on-topic here. Understand that network models are just models, and the real world often differs in specifics, but it is important to understand the concept of network layers, abstraction, and encapsulation.